# How to debug rsync failure on non-standard remote port

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to rsync some dir to a remote server which runs ssh on a non-standard port (443). The command and output/error looks like so:

```
$ rsync  -av somedir -e "ssh -p 443"  rsync://root@somehost:443/some/path

Enter passphrase for key '/home/my/.ssh/id_rsa': 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I use the `-e "ssh -p 443"` string before remote node spec as I found that this is required when ssh is running on a non-standard port. How should I go about debugging this problem?

Comment: ssh by default does not accept root logins and you need a rsync service running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync://` should be used when you directly connect to a remote `rsync` daemon (this obviously requires the daemon to be running on the remote system).

Here, you want to use `ssh` for communication between local and remote copies. The correct syntax will be:

```
$ rsync -av -e "ssh -p 443" somedir root@somehost:/some/path
```